# Is it possible to create a django_tenant_superuser via management.call_command?

Tags: django, django-users, django-manage.py, django-management-command

I'm building a multi-tenant project with django-tenant.

The issue I'm encountering is that "password" is not a valid flag option.

```
    management.call_command(
        'create_tenant_superuser', 
        interactive = False,
        username = "user"
        password = "password"
        )
```

gives error:

```
TypeError: Unknown option(s) for create_tenant_superuser command: password Valid options are: ...
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `call_command` when you can directly create the user? Use the [`create_superuser` (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_superuser) method of the user model's manaager.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat because I am using a django-tenants package that wraps create_superuser in it's own code in order to only create superuser for particular tenant / in particular postgres schema.

Comment: I am already directly creating a superuser within a tenant app, but right now I'm trying to create an api which registers tenants and their superusers; package only provides a CLI command for that : create_tenant_superuser

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify this there. I have posted an answer that will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`schema_context` [django-tenants docs]](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html#schema_context) context manager to make queries to specific schemas by providing the schema name:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django_tenants.utils import schema_context


UserModel = get_user_model()

with schema_context(schema_name):
    UserModel.objects.create_superuser(username="user", password="password")
```